# Android REST webservices

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I have a code which works perfectly on the java project but when i use the same on the android project it throws error here is the code .(Note i cannot share link and parameters, problem is NOT there . link is right . the code is working i am getting result in java project in eclipse but same in android project fails  )

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
try{
        Client client=Client.create();  
        WebResource webResource2 = client.resource("some...link");

        WSDetPojo wsdetpojo = new WSDetPojo(); // some class
        wsdetpojo.parameter1("parameter1");
        wsdetpojo.parameter2("parameter2");
        wsdetpojo.parameter3("parameter3");
        wsdetpojo.parameter4("parameter4");


        ObjectMapper om=new ObjectMapper();

        ClientResponse response2 = webResource2.type("application/json")
        .post(ClientResponse.class,om.writeValueAsString(wsdetpojo)); // here is the problem <==

        System.out.println("response of sms ==> "+response2);
        if (response2.getStatus() != 201) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+ response2.getStatus());

        }

        String output2 = response2.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("output :\n" +output2);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now here is the error which i get when i run it on android

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate$HeaderDelegate.fromString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.PartialRequestBuilder.type(PartialRequestBuilder.java:92)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.type(WebResource.java:347)
    at co.example.punerto.classes.NicClient.sendData(NicClient.java:43)
    at com.example.punerto.Activity.ActivityLearnLicAppointment_Tab6$uploadFrom.doInBackground(ActivityLearnLicAppointment_Tab6.java:303)
    at com.example.punerto.Activity.ActivityLearnLicAppointment_Tab6$uploadFrom.doInBackground(ActivityLearnLicAppointment_Tab6.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Please help !! Stuck on this spent 8 hours already . I also tried alternative did not worked !! If you have some alternative for this please do let me know.

Comment: I am using emulator.

Comment: the imported files in case if you are wondering which libs am i using      import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same sh!t. It works in JUnit but not on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the required android permissions ?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Are you connecting to your own local resources ? something like http://localhost:8080/blablabla ?? if yes you should change it to your local IP address: 192.168.1.1:8080/blablabla

Comment: No its not local resource its external link

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is too complicated to understand what is the problem when you are showing only your objects for storing your result and makeing the post request.
This is deprecated but still works fine for me in Android and might be useful for you to find your error.

```
    try {
        //Create an HTTP client
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://www...."); //your url as String
        //use HttpPost instead HttpGet if you need the post method
        //Perform the request and check the status code
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();

            try {
                //Read the server response 
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

                //get your data from the reader

                content.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed with: " + ex);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Server responded with status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);
    }
```